# create column based on pattern sql oracle

Tags: sql

I m learning window functions and trying to solve this

Table is:

```
colA         colB           colC         colD
70           3021           1234         a
69           3021           1234         b
68           3021           1234         a
67           3021           5678         a
2            4153           9170         b
1            4153           9170         a
```

Output required is:

```
colA         colB           colC         colD      output
70           3021           1234         a         2
69           3021           1234         b         (null)
68           3021           1234         a         1
67           3021           5678         a         1
2            4153           9170         b         (null)
1            4153           9170         a         1
```

What I tried

```
select *,row_number() over (partition by colB,colC order by colA,colB)
from table;
```

This would provide the row number throughout but need row number only for colD=a

For a group of colB and colC , row number needs to be generated only where colD='a'.

Example, for group of colB and colC (3021 and 1234), output is incremental row number 1 and 2 where `colD=a`, else output is `null`

Comment: can you describe the required output of the calculated column ? where the 3  and the null are coming from ?

Comment: Is there a primary key on that table? What is it?

Comment: The required output is the incremental row number with partition by across `colB and colC` and `row number to be defined only when colD=a`. When colD=b, output is `null`, Thanks!

Comment: @hayagane Please edit and add any clarification to your Question. Do not just provide those in comments. Also, I did not understand your explanation here.

Comment: How come output is 3 for first row in your expected output ?

Comment: Sorry! I have added the explanation and the output, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows and `case` to assign the values:

```
select t.*,
       (case when cold = 'a'
             then row_number() over (partition by colb, cold order by cola)
        end) as output
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below way -

```
select *,
  case when cold='a' then count(case when cold='a' then cold end) 
           over(partition by colb order by cola) end as output
from t1 order by cola desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your expected output , below should work

```
select t.*,case 
            when cold = 'a'
            then row_number() over (partition by colb, colc,cold order by cola)
           end as output
from table1 t order by cola desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact output as expected.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2700d/25)

```
select * from (
SELECT A.*, CASE WHEN COLD = 'a' then row_number() over(partition by colb, colc order by colb , colc, cold, cola ) else null end as rn
from table1 a ) order by 1 desc ;
```